# Database Error when insert data with loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, mysqli

I want to insert data in database with dynamic php variable and when I check the script in database I have only one record :(

```
$low_0 = 0;
$low_1 = 1;
$low_2 = 2;
$nr = 9;

for ($i = 0; $i < $nr; $i++) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO prognoza_curenta (ora, prognoza, min, max, reg_date)
            VALUES (' . "${'low_' . $i}, " . "11," . "22," . "33," . "'$timp')";
    echo "$sql" . "<br>";
}

if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    echo 'Data send' . "<br>";
} else {
    echo 'Error send.' . mysqli_error($sql) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: you miss to run `mysqli_query` inside loop. Also you can concatenate the `$sql` and only one time.  $sql .= 'INSERT....';

Comment: Start by learning to use prepared statements with bind variables in your SQL queries, ad then you wouldn't need to worry about horribly mangling your strings in this way

Comment: You are overwriting $sql and only the last loop remains for when you insert it.

Comment: Thx for all tips it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO prognoza_curenta (ora, prognoza, min, max, reg_date)  VALUES';
for ($i = 0; $i < $nr; $i++) {
    $sql .= ' (' . "${'low_' . $i}, " . "11," . "22," . "33," . "'$timp')";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Solution With prepared Statement:**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO prognoza_curenta (ora, prognoza, min, max, reg_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $ora, $prognoza, $min, $max, $reg_date);

// set parameters and execute
for ($i = 0; $i < $nr; $i++) {
    $ora= ${'low_' . $i};
    $prognoza= "11";
    $min= '22';
    $max = '33';
    $reg_date = $timp;
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

As Suggested by `@MarkBaker`, This is procedure of prepare statement. Please let me know.